# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined for a custom jQuery calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to implement a [jquery range calendar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Plugin-For-Date-Range-Selector-Range-Calendar.html) to an existing project, but I am getting the error from the title. Probably the reason behind this is a trivial one, but I just don't have sufficient expertise in order to solve it.

So, [here](https://pastebin.com/DS1HNX8C) is the code for the calendar.

I am including it in the project along with other js files in this way :

```
string closureBegin = "(function(jq) { if(jq != null) $ = jq; ";

    js.AddInline(IncludePosition.Head, closureBegin, closureBegin.GetHashCode().ToString());
    js.Add(IncludePosition.Head, "v1.1/js/control/jquery.rangecalendar.js");//range calendar
    js.Add(IncludePosition.Head, "v1.1/js/control/moment+langs.min.js");//moment plus langs
    js.Add(IncludePosition.Head, "v1.1/js/control/control.js");
```

jQuery is included and used in this project, so I don't know whatexactly is the reason for this error.

I managed to bypass it only by putting the range calendar code in a function, but that is not really a solution.

Here is the error from the console :

> > Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>
> ```
> at /c/js/js_2d42ca0e_12.19.0.dev.js:759
> at /c/js/js_2d42ca0e_12.19.0.dev.js:11468
> ```

Can someone please help?

Comment: check order of scripts in page. jQuery.js must load before any plugins and dependent code

Comment: Did you import jQuery into your page?

Comment: it is imported, yes